# APNS Integration 3010 error

Tags: apple-push-notifications

Followed following steps:
Added :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

Then implemented,

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}
```

But, Got following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo=0x90445d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
```

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message is shown when your iOS app attempts to register for push notifications while it is running in the iOS simulator.

The error explains that push notifications are not supported when the app is running in the simulator. The app must be running on a device to register for push notifications.